# How to do a SQL like INNER JOIN on multiple Python dictionaries

Tags: python, json, django

I am currently planning out a django app that allows users to not only build custom tables associated with models (e.g., a user could create a trivial custom "parking spot" table that is associated with the "employee" model without having to edit models.py), but to also build custom reports using those custom tables. The only way I can think to do this is by having a model that stores custom table data in a JSONField (I'm using Postgres as a backend so this actually works out great), and then have a reports model that allows users to build and save "SQL-like" queries that return joined datasets for their custom reports.

I've figured out how to store the custom tables and use them in my app, and I even have a loose concept on how to merge multiple JSON objects on pseudo foreign keys to be pulled into custom reports, but I have only gotten as far as creating **one-to-one** joins.

With the script below, if any of my dicts have multiple records on a single foreign key only the last record is used. Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish a **one-to-many** join of multiple python dictionaries?

If I have these three datasets:

```
employees = [{"id": 1, "user_id": 303, "name": "Mike"},
             {"id": 2, "user_id": 304, "name": "James"},
             {"id": 3, "user_id": 305, "name": "David"},]

roles = [{"id": 1, "user_id": 303, "role": "Manager"},
         {"id": 2, "user_id": 304, "role": "Assistant"},
         {"id": 3, "user_id": 305, "role": "Assistant"},]

absences = [{"id": 1, "user_id": 303, "date": "2015-03-01"},
            {"id": 2, "user_id": 303, "date": "2015-03-02"},
            {"id": 3, "user_id": 303, "date": "2015-03-03"},
            {"id": 4, "user_id": 304, "date": "2015-03-15"},
            {"id": 5, "user_id": 305, "date": "2015-03-19"},]
```

My desired outcome on a straight join would be:

```
[{'date': '2015-03-01', 'role': 'Manager', 'user_id': 303, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Mike'},
    {'date': '2015-03-02', 'role': 'Manager', 'user_id': 303, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Mike'},
    {'date': '2015-03-03', 'role': 'Manager', 'user_id': 303, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Mike'}, 
    {'date': '2015-03-15', 'role': 'Assistant', 'user_id': 304, 'id': 2, 'name': 'James'}, 
    {'date': '2015-03-19', 'role': 'Assistant', 'user_id': 305, 'id': 3, 'name': 'David'}]
```

but since my script loops through my FROM dictionary first (in this case, employees), all I am able to get is this:

```
[{'date': '2015-03-03', 'role': 'Manager', 'user_id': 303, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Mike'},
{'date': '2015-03-15', 'role': 'Assistant', 'user_id': 304, 'id': 2, 'name': 'James'},
{'date': '2015-03-19', 'role': 'Assistant', 'user_id': 305, 'id': 3, 'name': 'David'}]
```

And here are the basics of my code:

```
def joiner(from_table, joins):
    report_data = []

    for row in from_table:
        new_row = row
        for table in joins:
            table_dict = table["table"]
            table_fk = table["fk"]
            for tdr in table_dict:
                if tdr[table_fk] == row[table_fk]:
                    for field in table["fields"]:
                        new_row[field] = tdr[field]
    report_data = from_table
    return report_data

join_tables = [{"table": roles, "fk": "user_id", "fields": ["role"]},
               {"table": absences, "fk": "user_id", "fields": ["date"]},
          ]
joiner(employees, join_tables)
```

The simplest fix I could think of was to start with the "absences" dict as the from_table instead of employees, but then that is a Many-to-One join, which would be very limiting for my purposes.

Also, if anyone has a better idea for building user created data schemas that can be merged in custom reports using django, I'm all ears. The only other solution I can think of would be to bypass django models entirely and just have all custom tables created, updated, and queried using straight SQL.

Comment: Why not use an actual database for this data instead? In any case, you should use *dictionaries*, mapping `id` to the rest of the data, making 'inner joins' trivial.

Comment: @martijn-pieters The application itself rests on a database, but the custom table data would be dynamically generated by the user, and so couldn't be predefined in the models.py file (this is a django app). Can you explain how it would be trivial to do a join that outputs a list of dictionaries with merged keys on the id, given that I would want the output [{"id": 1, "day": "Monday"}, {"id": 1, "day": "Tuesday"}]? Wouldn't merging it just give me [{"id": 1, "day": "Tuesday"} since the id is not unique?

Comment: Right, if your ids are not unique you cannot do that; you'd have to use lists and the whole thing becomes more complicated. You don't *have* to use Django models, just perform [direct sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Comment: Yeah I use raw sql queries for a number of other things, but I didn't want to go that route for this because it just seemed like a pain. But if its the only solution I can probably figure out a flow that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you put the longest list of dictionaries first (Can be easily modified) when you call the merge, here is a crude solution

```
    def merge_lists(listdict1, listdict2,listdict3, joinkey):
        mergedlist=listdict1
        for i in range(len(listdict1)):
            for j in range(len(listdict2)):
                if (listdict1[i][joinkey]==listdict2[j][joinkey]):
                    for keys in listdict2[j].keys():
                        mergedlist[i][keys]=listdict2[j][keys]
            for k in range(len(listdict3)):
                if listdict1[i][joinkey]==listdict3[k][joinkey]:
                    for keys in listdict3[k].keys():
                        mergedlist[i][keys]=listdict3[k][keys]                       
        return mergedlist

    merge_lists(absences, employees, roles,  "user_id")


[  
   {  
      "date":"2015-03-01",
      "id":1,
      "name":"Mike",
      "role":"Manager",
      "user_id":303
   },
   {  
      "date":"2015-03-02",
      "id":1,
      "name":"Mike",
      "role":"Manager",
      "user_id":303
   },
   {  
      "date":"2015-03-03",
      "id":1,
      "name":"Mike",
      "role":"Manager",
      "user_id":303
   },
   {  
      "date":"2015-03-15",
      "id":2,
      "name":"James",
      "role":"Assistant",
      "user_id":304
   },
   {  
      "date":"2015-03-19",
      "id":3,
      "name":"David",
      "role":"Assistant",
      "user_id":305
   }
]
```